# Open PPTX file in iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to open .pptx file to  but when I open my file to brawswer its starts to download the file. For that i am using that code :-

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://download.ppt-to-dvd.com/tem/wedding2.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Its start to download file. But this code working for ppt,potx Please help how to show .pptx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me :-

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/labnol.org/viewer?url=carbon-choices-lesson.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is working fine as external URL. But how could we view locally uploaded ppt files in the iframes. It reads like blob:http://localhost:3000/filename. Kindly respond if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the .pptx file in the iframe based on this [thread](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-read-or-display-PDF-doc-docx-ppt-and-pptx-on-my-website-in-a-specific-iframe) but you can try this [solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/2101275.aspx?Display+PPTX+in+html+iframe+tag+) and see if this will work for your issue.